# Add a character count near a TextField in a SilverStripe Form

Tags: javascript, php, silverstripe

I want to add a character count to a `TextField` in a SilverStripe 2.4 `Form`.

When ever a user enters data in the `TextField` I want to show a message right beside or underneath the field displaying how many characters are left.

I have a JavaScript and Ajax call to count and post the character count, but if I try to display it by using  by using `LiteralField` going to another `<div>` which is not my option, any other `HTML tags` going out of `Form`.

Note: SilverStripe creates a separate `div` for each `Field` in the `Form`, because of that I am not able to  show any thing to the right of that field or the bottom of it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this Jquery code :

```
$(".TextField").onchange(function(event)
{
    $(event.target).closest(".silverstripe2.4 TextFiled").textContent = $(event.target).val().length;
}
```